# JSON Views in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm migrating a Grails 2.2.5 app to Grails 4.0.2, and I have it working OK but now want to start taking advantage of new features that came in with Grails 3 and 4, such as improvements in the area of JSON responses. I've been having a play with JSON Views and the use of respond, and have some test methods working. Still struggling in some areas, though. For example, I have in multiple places in controllers code which produces a Map, which I then return via `render map as JSON`. This works fine, with the JSON representation of the objects in the map being determined by customer marshallers using `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(MyClass)`. 
My understanding is that the use of respond and JSON Views for such things is now being encouraged, in preference to the `render xxx as JSON` approach (please correct me if I'm wrong). So two questions arise from this:

1. For my 'weekSummary' method in my SaleController, for this to work I presumably need to create a 'weekSummary.gson' file in /sale/views. What should that gson file look like? I've tried with e.g.

   `model {
    Map map
   }
   json map`

but this just renders null. How do I handle maps in JSON views?

2. What advantages does this give me over `render xxx as JSON`, given that it is a little more cumbersome (having to create a new GSON file)?

Comment: "What should that gson file look like?" - That depends on what is in the `Map` and what you want the generated JSON to look like.

Comment: Well, effectively I'm just looking for the equivalent of what `render map as GSON` does, but using the views technique. `render map as JSON` just uses what is currently set as the default marshaller for each object in the map.